# How to enable automatic updates for alpha/beta testers at Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, beta, beta-testing, google-groups

I have configured the alpha/beta tests at the Google Play Store.
New Google Group has been created for that purposes and required users were invited and joined the group.

When new update is available users have to go by the alpha/beta link to download and install the update.
Is there any option to push update to alpha/beta testers (like prod Play Store works)?

Comment: Alpha and beta updates are rolled out just like all other updates. Your users do not have to download the app through that link at all. They just have to be a part of the Google+ group and join the beta/alpha program through the link.

Comment: They are the part of the program as I described above and they didn't receive the update automatically. The only different is that they joined the Google Group (googlegroups.com) NOT Google+ group (I'm not aware about Google+ groups)

Comment: Are you aware that the rollout of an update takes a few hours? They don't get it instantly, but they do get it as long as they are testers, it just takes a while.

Comment: There is a day or two time frame involved with population through the store.  googlegroups.com is the way I have my beta setup.

Comment: I have delay in about day and after that had to update manually. So users can do nothing but wait and their version will be updated automatically? Will they receive a notification at the notification center?

Comment: my beta version code is 4 which is already available with few beta testers and i updated version to 5 in beta itself, now will my beta testers receive an app update notification from the play store?

Answer (score 6):

I believe what is happening is that you did not send the "become a tester" link to your testers for them to click.

Apparently the part where you add the Google Group or Google+ Community to the Alpha/Beta testers on the Google Play Developers console you did all OK.

But also there on the console you'll get a link that is: `https://play.google.com/apps/testing/<your app package name>`

all those users/testers MUST click this link and click on the button "Become a tester" for it to work.

After that initial setup is done, your users should receive automatic updates just like normal production version.

hope it helps.

Comment: I did send that link. Users press "become a tester" and after that click on link provided below the "become a tester" to download and install the app. After new update they have to hit the link again, but next they already a testers and what they are doing is downloading the app and installing manually

Comment: so, why did you accept the answer, and is there a resolution to your problem? i am having the same issue.

Comment: I am also having the same issue. It always has to be updated manually.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. It's been nearly a week since the latest alpha version went live. When I look on the play store, the update button is available for me. The app is on the list of Google play apps available to update. Other apps in that list are updating, but my app remains out of date and will still not update automatically.

Comment: my beta version code is 4 which is already available with few beta testers and i updated version to 5 in beta itself, now will my beta testers receive an app update notification from the play store?

Comment: I'm having the same issue with my app that it's currently in Alpha version. Testers don't get automatic updates.

Comment: Did anybody get this fixed?